# Table 'nova.services' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, openstack, openstack-nova

OpenStack Rocky

nova-manage cell_v2 simple_cell_setup command not work

[image]

tail -f /var/log/nova/nova-api log

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: mysql is always right in these things. use phpomyadmin or workbench and chekc  the database nova if it has that tablename, check also for mispelling or added characters

Comment: Add more context to the question. Such as: Is there a nova database? Does it have any tables, and which tables? How was this cloud deployed? Has is ever worked?

Comment: Also please don't paste pictures but actual terminal output (using code tags), that makes it a lot easier.